# Obtener lista de una colección en Firebase Android

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy desarrollando un aplicativo que almacena datos en Firebase. Actualmente estoy guardando una lista de String en un documento de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList<String> listaUIDproyectos = new ArrayList<String>();
listaUIDproyectos.add("Casa");
listaUIDproyectos.add("Carro");
listaUIDproyectos.add("Perro");

Map<String, Object> objeto = new HashMap<>();
objeto.put("datos", listaDatos);
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("coleccion")
                .document(uid)
                .update(objeto)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(this,"OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Utilidades.alertDialogSimple(getActivity(), "Error: " + e.toString());
            }
        });
```

Quisiera saber como podría obtener esta lista haciendo consulta a Firebase, gracias.

Actualización en tiempo real con Cloud Firestore

Comment: En la documentación oficial, puedes encontrar información al respecto. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=es-419

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haciendo la siguiente consulta podrías obtener la lista

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
ListenerRegistration listener = db.collection("coleccion")
.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
@Override
public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e){
if(e != null){
   return;
}
for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : queryDocumentSnapshots){
   Object listaRecibida = document.get("datos");
   ArrayList<String> lista = (ArrayList<String>) listaRecibida;
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: Gracias, me funcionó como quería